# Why is Facebook PHP SDK getUser always returning 0? Opencart

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, opencart2.x

I am getting `0` as a result while accessing `$this->fbconnect->getUser();` in FB login in **OpenCart2.1.x**.

Below is the code, that i am using:

- In `register` controller, i am making URL as below:

  ```
  if(!$this->customer->isLogged()){
             if(!isset($this->fbconnect)){            
      require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'facebook/facebook.php');
      $this->fbconnect = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $this->config->get('facebook_apikey'),
          'secret' => $this->config->get('facebook_apisecret'),
           'redirect_uri'  => $this->url->link('facebook/facebook', '', 'SSL'),
           'cookie' => true,
           'domain'=>'abc.com'
      ));
     }

     $data['facebook_url'] = $this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl(
      array(
          'scope' => 'public_profile, email',
          'redirect_uri'  => $this->url->link('facebook/facebook', '', 'SSL')
      )
     );
  }
  ```

and in `register.tpl` the URL is fine and i am being redirected to FB login page for authentication. but after login while returning back to  my website, i am getting `0` for `getUser()` function.

- The `Facebook` Controller in `catalog/controller/facebook/facebook.php` the code is like below:

  ```
  if(!isset($this->fbconnect)){           
      require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'facebook/facebook.php');

      $this->fbconnect = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $this->config->get('fbconnect_apikey'),
          'secret' => $this->config->get('fbconnect_apisecret'),
           'redirect_uri' => $this->url->link('facebook/facebook', '', 'SSL'),
      ));
  }

  $_SERVER_CLEANED = $_SERVER;
  $_SERVER = $this->clean_decode($_SERVER);

  echo $fbuser = $this->fbconnect->getUser();  **0**
  ```

Full code can be found here:: [Click Here](https://github.com/funky-i/OpenCart-Facebook-Login/blob/master/catalog/controller/facebook/facebook.php)

My App Settings are:

[image]

Here:: `abc.com` means that my actual website URL will be replaced here.

> Please do not mark this question as **DUPLICATE** because i have already searched on SO and everywhere and nothing is working here for me. So, please try to give the solution and that is i am posting question after searching for more than 1 day.

Comment: Where you are querying the user data? [see this Graph API User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user)

Comment: I did not get.. can you explain more

Comment: To get data you first need to query facebook for that data; In this case as you are trying to get the id of user then first you have to query user data from facebook then you will get the id you want;

Comment: I am using exact same code that i have mentioned in the link above. So, can you figure out where i am doing wrog

Comment: But i there is no such code that making get request to facebook server to get user details?

Comment: I really do not have any idea.. If you have any clue, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

Replace

```
echo $fbuser = $this->fbconnect->getUser();
```

with

```
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $this->fbconnect->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Id: ' . $user['id'];
echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
```

Comment: This return Fatal error: `Call to undefined method Facebook::get()`

Comment: i replcaed PHP SDK with PHP 5 SDK and used combined approach for JS and PHP SDK :)